How to Correctly Place Inline Comments in JSX?
I'm learning React and trying to add inline comments within JSX. However, using the usual JavaScript // comments results in a syntax error. Here's a snippet of my code:
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App /> // Trying to comment here about the 'App' component
  </BrowserRouter>
);

This results in SyntaxError: 'Unexpected token, expected' . Could someone explain why this happens and how to correctly add comments within JSX?
I'm new to Stack Overflow, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

See for example https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-comments-in-jsx

Single line comment:
{/* single line comment */}

Multiline list comment
{/* Multiline 
comment */}

